# pyvmomi get total cpu, memory stat of vcenter server

Tags: python, api, vmware, vcenter, pyvmomi

I am able to get cpu memory of different objects like hosts, datacenter through the api. But i need the total CPU, memory statistics of the whole vcenter as shown in the pic below using pyvmomi. Any help would be appreciated. [image]

Comment: I'm not finding a suitable example, but you're looking for the vCenter Resource (vcres) counters that are part of the PerformanceManager: https://code.vmware.com/apis/358/vsphere#/doc/vcres_counters.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop through and get the hosts after connecting to vCentre with SmartConnect

The host hardware information is located [here](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk25pubs/ReferenceGuide/vim.host.HardwareInfo.html)

Once you have the hosts you loop through them and get the hardware details. They are in raw format so you have to convert them. I've pasted the convertMemory function I use

```
hosts = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(content.rootFolder,[vim.HostSystem],True)
for host in hosts.view:
    # Print the hosts cpu details
    print(host.hardware.cpuInfo)
    # convert CPU to total hz to ghz times numCpuCores
    print("CPU:", round(((host.hardware.cpuInfo.hz/1e+9)*host.hardware.cpuInfo.numCpuCores),0),"GHz")
    #covert the raw bytes to readable size via convertMemory
    print("Memory:", convertMemory(host.hardware.memorySize))
```

The convertMemory function just converts the number to readable memory

```
def convertMemory(sizeBytes):
    name = ("B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB")
    base = int(floor(log(sizeBytes, 1024)))
    power = pow(1024,base)
    size = round(sizeBytes/power,2)
    return "{}{}".format(floor(size),name[base])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had thought going through all the hosts and summing up the statistics for summary.